# Redux Multiple Types In An Action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Just a quick convention question. I have this code working in a redux action of mine. The code works fine but I am unsure if this is accepted among the community or not. Basically I am passing two dispatches in the same action with the goal of passing two seperate actions and payloads. I was getting an error when I tried to pass two types as an array to one type. But I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it? Or if I should just drop it and have two separate actions all together.

Thank You!

```
dispatch({
  type: GET_WALLET,
  payload: mnemonic
});
dispatch({
  type: AUTHENTICATION,
  payload: false
});
```

Comment: This is okay, you can also give redux-thunk or redux-saga a try if you want to achieve async behavior.

Comment: while it's most opinion based, `redux` team [suggests avoiding such a case](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#avoid-dispatching-many-actions-sequentially) and describe separate "combined" action instead. Why? because each `dispatch` will synchronously re-render your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate it into two action creators and make it more clean

```
const getWallet = (mnemonic) => ({ type: GET_WALLET, payload: mnemonic });

const auth = () => ({ type: AUTHENTICATION, payload: false });

dispatch(getWallet(mnemonic));
dispatch(auth());
```